# how to get ellipsize working with three textviews side by side

Tags: android, textview

I've been spending some hours trying to figure this problem out, and maybe I'm missing something obvious...

I'm trying to get three TextViews placed side by side working. I want all of them to be equally large, no matter what text they contain, and if the text won't fit in one of them, the text should be replaced by "..." at the end in that particular textview (with help of ellipsize).

| <>TextView>>      <>TextView>>      <>TextView> |

As I said, I need them to be equally large at all times. This can "easily" be done by a LinearLayout using weights, however then ellipsize won't work (or at least I won't get it working), since it seems you need an absolute width size to get it to work.

I've been trying with LinearLayouts, RelativeLayouts, TableLayouts, and finally I went with a combination of an xml layout and a programatically approach (this seems far more advanced than it needs to be, but that was the only way I was able to become close). However, now I use an absolute width (setting it programatically), but although I'm multiplying it with a proper densitymultiplier, it will look different on different screens. On a 4.3" screen there will be some space over which I could have used, on the other hand on a 2.7" screen it looks pretty good.

So any ideas how I can achieve this with a layout? I've been looking around a bit on forums as well, the problem is that most people only want one textview to have the ellipsize function, and not all of them...

Below you'll find my first attempt to get it working, but since I think an absolute width is needed in order for ellipsize to work, it won't work. Setting the width to "1dp" for example won't really do the trick either.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"

    >
         <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:editable="true"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:singleLine="true"
          >
          </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:editable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
         >
       </TextView>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="right"
          android:editable="true"       
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:singleLine="true"       
        >
      </TextView>   
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me when I removed the `android:editable="true"` part.

If you want that to be a user-editable field use `EditText` instead. That one (afaik) does not support ellipsize though.

Comment: Although a bit late (accepting the answer), this solved my problem. Android can be really annoying sometimes, can't believe how many hours I sat trying to fix this when the solution was that simple. Thanks!